# Crystal Reports on ASP.NET: How to make the first page visible faster

Tags: asp.net, performance, crystal-reports, perception

In ASP.NET application, while using Crystal Reports (using the Report Viewer control), the report is visible (or the data in the report) only after the complete data is bound to the report source. If the data is too huge (spanning 50 or hundreds of pages), the data binding takes a while. Can there be some technique to better the perceived speed by making the first page data visible as the data for the first page is bound? The rest of the data can be bound by the time the user sees the first page.

Comment: silly answer, please dont vote down. can you put page 1-5 in the main report an 6-??? in a sub report??? might load the first few immediately and marginally defer the rest.

Comment: Thanks for putting it as comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Seems, there is no way known so far.

Answer (score 0):

paginate the sql query for resultset to bind first page only to the report.

http://josephlindsay.com/archives/2005/05/27/paging-results-in-ms-sql-server/

Comment: I am not sure, one can use paging with crystal reports. Does crystal report bring in the next pages of results from database automatically? If not, how can one automate this?

Comment: hmm, user have to click on controls outside the report

Comment: So this is not in any way comes closer to the possible answer for the post. You may please edit the same.